# Convert std::complex<float> into a pybind11::object

Tags: pybind11

I have a `std::complex<float>` and want to use pybind11 to convert that value into a temporary `pybind11::object` (storing a `complex` python value). How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `pybind11::cast`.

```
std::complex<float> a{1, 2};
pybind11::object obj = pybind11::cast(a);
```